# Image upload with ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to create a page where users can upload photos with ajax. I have tried many plugins but the are not fitting my needs. I want a simple uploader without much hectic. Can anyone tell me how can I do this without using a plugin or can anyone suggest me a plugin that dont interfere in ui and just do the work of taking the image, validating it and sending it to the server side page. 
I have tried the following plugins:

1) Blueimp
2) Valums image uploader
3) Uploadify

Valums file uploader is interfering the ui. Blueimp's integration is too hard and uncomfortable. Uploadify is using flash. I don't want to use flash or iframes. This is a serious application and quality of code is really really important.

Answer (score 0):

you have no choice but to use flash or iframes. you can't send a file any other way.

You can implement plugins however that do the iframe or flash work for you.

My personal favorite is to add a new transport to jquery called iframe that allows you to upload using hidden iframes with jquery's $.ajax method.

http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2011/07/jquery-ajax-transports

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample .

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Here are some other in case any of them helps .

http://www.tutorialchip.com/jquery/9-powerful-jquery-file-upload-plugins/